# Why creation of universe in 6 days

Tags: islamic-philosophy, creation

Why did it take Allah 6 days to create the universe?

I know that Allah is independent of time, but I have trouble understanding why the creation of the universe *took* as long as it did.  Please help me to clarify that.

Comment: @goldPseudo Please don't use the work "takes" or "took", instead use spend (as time spent is by choice not due to limitation)

Comment: yes my bad tanx

Comment: Maybe it took like a second to create the universe, but our and his time perception is different. Time is relative. It might mean that if he were to create another universe and we were to witness it, it would take 6 days for us to see it be created from nothing to its last state.

Answer (score 2):

It takes Allah nine months to create a baby. Things go through a natural process. That is Allah decree for them. It is His rules and he can break them if he wants.

The exact term used in Quran can also be translated as "stages". Each stage can be of millions of years.

Comment: Tanx goto i get it sob7ana ALLah the greatest

Answer (score 1):

Allah created universe in 6 days doesn't mean he could't create it in the trillion'th of a second. It didn't take Allah 6 days(or time periods) but Allah did this intentionally. Allah is "Ala kuli shai'in qadir' - able to do all things.

Now why He chose six days instead of infinite part of a second is His wish. We can think of possible reasons:

**Reason 1:** Allah doesn't need us we need Him. He doesn't need universe but everything in universe needs him. Since this world was created to test us, so creating it in stages helped human beings to understand it and praise His glory. There is a good proportion in our intelligence and the speed at which things got created in this universe so that we can study them through science. This is just an opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The creation of the world cited in the Quran is first told in the beginning of Tenach (Bereshit/1.Mose). It is one week minus the day. This seventh day is the Shabbath, the day of rest and prayer in the Jewish tradition.

We know that in fact, Allah has been forming the world for thousands of million years.

The creation in six days is a myth. I use the word myth in its original meaning, not to be unserstood as something that is simply not true, but telling a complex of truthes:

- It tells that God has made heaven and earth
- It tells what came first, and that we men came last
- It contradicts other (Sumeric, Babylonian, ...) myths that describe the beginning of the earth as a fight of an immense number of divinities, instead stating that there is one God from whom all comes.
- It tells us that God has made us.
- It lets us marvel about the power of God
- It tells us that God is ther ruler of the universe.
- It tells that God has prepared for us, for the animals and the plants that we can live.
- Yes, and it gives a reason for the day of Shabbath

This myth is not *revealed* with the Quran but often *cited* just to extract such thruth from it. Mostly, the number of six days is cited therewith, but it is never the subject of the truth to explain; in particular the custom of one day dedicated to God is less emphasized in the Quran than in Jewish books and tradition, therefore we have been advised to perform more prayers on all days to remind us that God is present in our entire lives.