# How long has mankind been on Earth?

Tags: creation, mankind

There are a couple of existing questions on the site [Is evolution compatible with Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/54/is-evolution-compatible-with-islam) & [Why creation of universe in 6 days](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12006/why-creation-of-universe-in-6-days) that discuss the creation of the Earth and evolution, they address considerations for a [Young Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_Earth_creationism).

By [some accounts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology_of_the_Bible) Adam came to be on Earth about 6,000 years ago. But these numbers seem to be based on a Christian/Jewish view.  What is the Islam view of the time man has been on Earth?

Comment: We do not believe in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a tradition (Hadith) which could be related with your inquiry. According to a tradition from Prophet Muhammad (SAWW), he said that:

> the world is 7.000 years and I am at the last millennium of it …

**Hence**, by paying attention to above-mentioned hadith we can figure it out that the maximum age of mankind couldn't be more than 7.000 years. (Even if we consider that e.g. Adam was created since the first day of the creation of the earth!)

---

**Reference**:

- [islamquest.net](http://islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa48482)

Comment: Where did you find the Hadith? Do you have a reference to a book and a number of reference?

Comment: Wait, obviously more than a millennium has passed since Prophet Muhammad, therefore he wasn’t in the last millennium. Also, what you said doesn’t make sense because if the Earth was 7000 years old at the time of the Prophet, it would be 8400 years now.

Answer (score 1):

Al-Ghazali in the text, *Deliverance from Error* wrote:

> 45. The physical sciences are a study of the world and it's stars; and of the sublunar simple bodies; such as water, air, earth and fire; and composite bodies such as animals, plants and minerals. They also study the causes of their changing and transformation and being mixed; this is like  medicines study of the human body...
>
> ...and just as Islam doesn't require the repudiation of the science of medicine, it doesn't require the repudiation of the science of physics; except for certain questions we have mentioned in the *[Incoherence of the Philosophers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Incoherence_of_the_Philosophers)*

Turning to that text, we don't see that there is a specific mention of the rage of the universe, or indeed the world; and nor would naming an age would directly contradict it either.

**Therefore**, we can take the standard age of the universe, and the earth into account as it is judged by the sciences of astronomy - and this is roughly 15 billion years for the universe, and 4 billion years for the Earth.